Error using xlwings to create a worksheet in a new workbook
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book()  
sheet = wb.sheets.add('trade_summary')

Produces the following error message:
CommandError: Command failed:
        OSERROR: -1728
        MESSAGE: The object you are trying to access does not exist
        COMMAND: app(pid=464).workbooks['Book13'].sheets['Sheet2'].name.get()


'Book13' sounds like you may have a few zombie Excel instances left over from previous runs, Try shutting down all Excel processes, check Task Manager, and try again.

I did that previously and got the same result.  I also  got the same error in python11.5.3 interpreter and Jupyter Notebook
